# Godot 4 upgrade: export array of flags

Tags: upgrade, godot, godot4

I'm upgrading a project from Godot 3 to Godot 4. In Godot 3 I had an export variable that was an array of bit flags. This essentially allowed me to set the number of a given item and set bit flags for each of the items.

Example:

```
export (Array, EnumOfFlags, FLAGS) var items:= [0, 1]: setget = _set_items
```

In upgrading to Godot 4, when I switch to the `@export_flags` syntax I'm running into two problems.

1. `@export_flags` won't accept an enum as an argument. I get this error when I try supplying `EnumOfFlags` as the only argument: `Invalid argument for annotation "@export_flags": argument 1 should be "String" but is "EnumOfFlags"`. This is annoying since using an enum allows me to reuse and reference the flags really cleanly. I can work around this.
2. `@export_flags` requires the variable to be an integer and doesn't like the concept of an array of bit flags. I get this error when I try to assign the array above as the default value: `"@export_flags" annotation requires a variable of type "int" but type "Array" was given instead.`. This is more problematic since I want different flags for each item. I can think of some possible workarounds but they involve writing significantly more code.

Are either of these still possible in Godot 4? The [docs suggest there are more advanced exports](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_exports.html#advanced-exports) but the [advanced exports section](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_exports.html#advanced-exports) seems to be incomplete (it gives some things you should be familiar with before reading more but then ends).